# typescript: call class destructor to remove an object from an array

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

just wondering something.
I find myself in this situation:

```
export class Legs {
  legs: Leg[];

  constructor(private modalCtrl:ModalController) {
    this.legs = []
  }

  addLeg(){
    this.legs.push(new Leg(this.modalCtrl));//Leg is a component rendered in a ngcontainer thru ngfor
  }

  removeLeg(i){
    this.legs.splice(i,1)
  }

}
```

is there a way to substitute the removeLeg() function to call it from the inside of the object Leg (created in AddLeg)?

I would imagine a button in the Leg html file calling the destructor.. 
would it work? would it destroy the object and remove it from the array Legs?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a reference from Leg to actual class (Legs)

```
new Leg(i,this, this.modalCtrl)
```

and next you can call from Leg something like:

```
legs.removeLeg(i)
```

or

```
legs.legs.splice(i,1)
```